# "for each file"-loop inside awk script

Tags: unix, for-loop, foreach, awk

I write now an AWK function, that should look like:

```
  function inser_styles(path_to_files, output_file) {
    for each input_file in path_to_files {
      print "" > output_file;
      while ( getline < input_file ) {
        print "   " $0 > output_file;
      }
    }
    print "" > output_file;
  }
```

It shoud read files from some `path_to_files` directory and put all the content of each `input_file` into some `output_file`, separated with empty line.

How could the `for each input_file in path_to_files {...}` - loop look like? Does the awk support this kind of for-loop or should I read the filename array with extern execute of `ls`?

Comment: the function is an AWK function (not a shell), so it is definde  within an AWK script.

Comment: AWK doesn't have its own globbing or directory walking functionality.

Comment: seems to be so. may be you know any proof links? (I didn't find anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` utility to get the filenames. Note that this will not work properly if filenames contain newlines. Specify any additional options that you'd like to use with `find`.

```
function insert_styles(path_to_files, output_file) {
    cmd = "find " path_to_files " -maxdepth 1 -type f"
    while (cmd | getline input_file > 0) {
        print "" > output_file;
        while ( getline < input_file ) {
            print "   " $0 > output_file;
        }
        close(input_file)
    }
    close(cmd)
    print "" > output_file;
}
```